# Golang mock a function with dynamic function calls

Tags: unit-testing, go, mocking

I'm pretty new to Go and still learning about how things work in Go, so with that said I've been looking in to Go testing approach and how mocking would work for the past few weeks and most of the information I found based on functions being concrete.

E.g. everything is a function is either passed as a receiver or a parameter, however, the problem I face is my function uses a switch case to determine what function it should be called, so it's not passed from outside.

```golang
func (n *Notification) Notify(m Message) error {
    switch n.Service {
    case "slack":
        var s slack.Slack
        s.User = m.User
        s.Host = m.Host
        s.Provider = m.Provider
        s.SystemUser = m.SystemUser
        return s.SlackSend(n.Url)
    default:
        return errors.New(codes.CODE5)
    }
}
```

Above code is what the function I want to test looks like and I'm having a hard time figuring out how I could mock the `SlackSend()` function.

I've come across some article say I should write the function in the test file and when I'm happy with what function do, I should write the real code. This doesn't sound right to me because for me it feels like I have the same code in two places and test only uses the one in test and I could change the real code and break it without testes detecting that.

I mainly work on Python and I'm used to using things like Mock/MagicMock that can intercept the function call and replace on at runtime, so apologies in advance if I don't quite get the Go's TDD approach.

This is what test code would look like if anyone wonders:

```golang
type MockSlack struct {
    *slack.Slack
}

func (s *MockSlack) SlackSend(url string) error {
    if url != "" {
        return nil
    } else {
        return errors.New("url empty")
    }
}

func TestNotify(t *testing.T) {
    m := Message{}
    n := Notification{
        Service: "slack",
        Url:     "https://dummy.io",
    }

    if err := n.Notify(m); err != nil {
        t.Errorf("SlackSend, expected: %s, got: %s", "nil", err.Error())
    }
}
```

Obviously the `MockSlack` structure is not taking effect because it's not really passed in anywhere.

If anyone has any advice on how I could mock this or what I should do instead would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

**UPDATE:**
*Background*

This isn't a web server/applicaition of a sort. It's an SSH authentication plugin so it would be a server-side application. As for Notify method, it server's the purpose of a mapper. So it can call Slack, MS Teams, AWS SNS which give caller less conditions to process and how and where the notification it sent is decided by the `Notify` method.

Comment: There are a few ways to ease testing such as using callbacks or implementing an interface similar to your example but this would require modifying the method `Notify` to make it testable. Are you able to do so?

Comment: Spend some time - let's say 4 hours - reading the tests of the stdlib. You'll see a lot of test patterns that work well for Go. Classical "mocking" doesn't work well. Using fakes and especially stubs is common and works great, mocking doesn't. Mocks like yours tend to test implementation details instead of functionality. Start a net/http/httptest.Server and let Notify actually make a HTTP call. That sounds crazy for most people coming from other languages but it works and tests your stuff better.

Comment: This also allows you to test all error paths, e.g. how wrong credentials, bad URLs, unresolvable hosts or timeouts are handled by your code. Your "mocked" test doesn't really test the interesting stuff of Notify.

Comment: if `n.Service` were an interface instead of a string...maybe the interface is named `Sender`...and your `Notification` struct was created with a constructor `NewNotification` that accepted a `Sender` interface param and returned `&Notification{Service: sender}`...then in your tests you could pass a fake sender to the constructor...and the resulting struct's Notify func would call the sender Send() func.

Senders of different types could have different implementations of course.

I would probably do it like that.

Comment: @Volker Thanks for the suggestion I'll look into that. This was partially my fault, I didn't give any background to what the application supposed to do. This isn't a web server of a sort. It's an SSH authentication plugin so it would be a server-side application. So some of the stuff that you've suggested I can actually use for the `SlackSend` method, which actually does HTTP calls. As for `Notify` method, it server's the purpose of a mapper. So it can call Slack, MS Teams, AWS SNS.

Comment: I do realise the most common use case of Go is for web application and me writing a standard application might not make things easier.

Comment: @jcorry Unfortunately, `n.Service` isn't determined by code. It's a string because of the value will come from a JSON configuration file at runtime so at the moment only have finished code for Slack and I would soon add AWS SNS to the mix so the user can define if should use Slack or SNS. Ideally, I'd like to keep it that way, if not I'd have to drop the `Notify` method and move that switch logic to the `main`. Which I'd like to avoid as much as I can. So `main` remains like a storyline; tells the users what it does rather than how it works.

Answer (score -1):

If you are not able to change the `Notify` Method to make it testing friendly. One option would be to consider using [monkeypatching](https://github.com/bouk/monkey). Here is an [example](https://github.com/bouk/monkey/blob/master/examples/instance_example.go) provided for `*net.Dialer`:

```golang
func main() {
    var d *net.Dialer // Has to be a pointer to because `Dial` has a pointer receiver
    monkey.PatchInstanceMethod(reflect.TypeOf(d), "Dial", func(_ *net.Dialer, _, _ string) (net.Conn, error) {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("no dialing allowed")
    })
    _, err := http.Get("http://google.com")
    fmt.Println(err) // Get http://google.com: no dialing allowed
}
```

#### WARNING: It's not safe to use it outside of a testing environment.